# Reading JNDI name from external properties file in Spring

Tags: spring, spring-mvc

I am developing a Spring web application where I am using JMS as well as some datasource connection.

Now Instead of hardcoding the JNDI names of DataSource/Jms Connection Factory,I want to read them from a external properties file.

I used the following configuration::

```
<bean id="myProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath*:myFile"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
 `<jee:jndi-lookup` id="dataSource" jndi-name="${DS_JNDI}" expected-type="javax.sql.DataSource"/>
```

But during deployment time it is throwing an error in weblogic:::

```
javax.naming.NameNotFoundException: Unable to resolve '${DS_JNDI}'. Resolved ''; remaining name '${DS_JNDI}'
```

Is it like that I cannot put a property file entry when using `<jee:jndi-lookup>`???

Comment: try giving the exact file name  Eg. <bean id="myProperties"
      class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean">
  <property name="locations">
    <list>
      <value>classpath*:myFile.properties</value>
    </list>
  </property>
</bean>

Comment: I think it appends .properties itself.
Moreover what is the need of going with PropertiesFactoryBean?We can use
PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer

Comment: Sorry, my bad.  'PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer' is what i intended to give.  Not sure whether it will appen '.properties' or not. hope you would have even tried avoiding the 'ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders' as its description says 'Use ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders to intentionally suppress throwing an exception if a placeholder cannot be resolved.'

Comment: Or you can go for a lighter version of it <context:property-placeholder ... /> and ensure that the file is in class path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
<bean id="myProperties"  class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertiesFactoryBean"> 
   <property name="locations"> 
      <list> 
         <value>classpath*:myFile.properties</value> 
      </list> 
   </property> 
</bean>
```

This is the correct solution of the problem.I think from Spring5.x onwards it has stopped appending ".properties" extension.

Answer (score 0):

you should remove the star after classpath, and add properties of file extension

```
<bean id="myProps" class="org.springframework.beans.factory.config.PropertyPlaceholderConfigurer">
    <property name="locations" value="classpath:myFile.properties"/>
    <property name="ignoreUnresolvablePlaceholders" value="true"/>
</bean>
```